# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \left\lfloor(1-e^x)\frac {\sin x}{|x|}\right\rfloor$

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How to simplify the following limit:$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left\lfloor(1-e^x)\frac {\sin x}{|x|}\right\rfloor,$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ represents the greatest integer function.

Given limit is in 0/0 form so can we apply
 LH rule to solve this problem.. or there is special approach for the same.

Comment: Use L'hopital's rule like you normally would, but with the limit $x \rightarrow 0^+$ and $x \rightarrow 0^-$ separately.

Comment: When you say greatest integer function are you talking about the floor or ceiling or rounding?

Comment: Yes.. you r correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, when $x$ is close enough to $0$, $$\left\lfloor(1-e^x)\frac{\sin x}{\lvert x\rvert}\right\rfloor=-1,\tag1$$your limit is equal to $-1$.

The fact that $(1)$ holds when $x$ is close enough to $0$ can be deduced from these facts:

- if $x$ is close to $0$ and $x>0$, then $0<\frac{\sin x}x=\frac{\sin x}{\lvert x\rvert}<1$. But $-1<1-e^x<0$, and therefore $(1-e^x)\frac{\sin x}{\lvert x\rvert}\in(-1,0)$;
- if $x$ is close to $0$ and $x<0$, then $0<\frac{\sin x}x<1$, and therefore $-1<\frac{\sin x}{\lvert x\rvert}<0$. Besides, $0<1-e^x<1$, and therefore $(1-e^x)\frac{\sin x}{\lvert x\rvert}\in(-1,0)$ too.

Comment: Explain your answer plz..

Comment: Done. What do you think now?

Comment: Thanks .. I understand completely right now...

Comment: over a night I thinking about how to solve this using LH rule ... Can you tell me the way to solve this . Using LH rule..

Comment: I don't see how to use L'Hospital's rule here.